# Add users to Custom Audience using Python - Facebook Ads API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to add users to a custom audience via API.

I only managed to create the custom audience, but I couldn't uderstand how can I add users there:

I've tried the code below:

```
      from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
        
      from facebook_business.adobjects.customaudience import CustomAudience
      from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
        
      access_token = 'ID'
      app_secret = 'ID'
      app_id = 'ID'
      my_account = AdAccount('act_ID')
      FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
        
      fields = []
      params = {
         'name': 'TEST',
         'subtype': 'CUSTOM',
         'description': 'Internal Data',
         'customer_file_source': 'USER_PROVIDED_ONLY',
       }
        
       audience = my_account.create_custom_audience(fields=[], params=params)
    
   schema = [
     MultiKeySchema.email,
     MultiKeySchema.phone,
     MultiKeySchema.ln,
     MultiKeySchema.fn
   ]
    
    
   payload = customaudience.CustomAudience.format_params(
               schema,[
                       ["john.doe@example.com", 3242424, "Doe", "john"],
                      ],
               is_raw=True,
           )
    
   my_account.get_api_assured().call(
               'POST',
               (audience, 'users'),
               params=payload,
           )
```

Thanks a lot!